# Change the value of input hidden in drupal form

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-9

I have two field on my screen: a **select** listing a list of user by their IDs and 2 **radio buttons**.

I'd like to change a value of a **hidden** input "has_photo" in *ajax *when the user changes the select value.

This is what my form looks like (extending FormBase) in the buildForm() :

```
    $form['card']['user'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#empty_option' => 'Choose',
      '#options' => $users,
      '#default_value' => $id_user,
      '#ajax' => [
        'method' => 'replace',
        'callback' => '::addPhotoWarning',
        'event' => 'change',
        'wrapper' => 'hasPhoto'
      ],
    ];

    $form['card']['hasPhoto'] = [
      '#type' => 'number',
      '#value' => $hasPhoto
    ];
```

And my ajax function :

```
  /**
   * @param array $form
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function addPhotoWarning(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $idUser = $form_state->getUserInput()['card']['user'] ? $form_state->getUserInput()['card']['user'] : NULL;
    if ($idUser) {
        $hasPhoto = $this->hasPhoto($idUser);
        $form['card']['user']['#value'] = $hasPhoto ? '1' : '0';
    }
    return $form['card']['hasPhoto'];
  }
```

The $form['card']['hasPhoto'] is a input type number, because I couldn't find out how to reload this value is I put use an hidden type, as the drupal ajax api requires a wrapper. I don't want to reload all the form when the user changes the value of the select (because user could have put other values in other input)

I'm using drupal 9.5

Answer (score 1):

You can add the new hasPhotoWrapper field:

```
$form['card']['hasPhotoWrapper'] = [
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => '<div id="hasPhoto"></div>',
];
```

and update the hasPhoto Field as

```
$form['card']['hasPhoto'] = [
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => $hasPhoto,
  '#prefix' => '<div id="hasPhoto">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
];
```

Also, Ajax callback as

```
public function addPhotoWarning(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $idUser = $form_state->getUserInput()['card']['user'] ? $form_state->getUserInput()['card']['user'] : NULL;
  if ($idUser) {
      $hasPhoto = $this->hasPhoto($idUser);
      $form['card']['hasPhoto']['#value'] = $hasPhoto ? '1' : '0';
  }
  return $form['card']['hasPhotoWrapper'];
}
```

Comment: Ended up by doing something like that,, thanks !